# How can I access the value of a key in a dictionary if the key is a tuple?

Tags: python, dictionary

so lets say I have this code

```
x = { (1,"name1"):5673,
      (2,"name2"):3265,
      (3,"name3"):6319,
      (4,"name4"):2539,
      (5,"name5"):1734,
    }
```

and I want to get 5673, I know I can do `x[(1,"name1")]` but I want to be able to either use the number or string so something like `x[0][1]` and get `5673` (the zero is to use the first index in the tuple and the 1 is for the first dictionary or what ever of them has number 1) for choosing by number or `x[1]["name2"]` we get `3265` to choose by string (also the 1 is to use the second index in the tuple and the "name2" is for the second dictionary or what ever of them has string "name2"), other examples would be we can use `x[0][3]` and get `6319` or use `x[1]["name5]` and get `1734`

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible unless you make `x` a list of dicts. Which I recommend doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing dictionaries with lists. You're trying to access a key of a dictionary using an index? That's not how it works. You can create multiple keys with the same value to be able to access the same value.

Answer (score 0):

With the way your data structure is setup, there unfortunately is no way to access values the way you described (eg. x[0][1]) without changing the structure. The following structures will allow you to use the method you want to access the various values.

```
x = [ {1: 5673, "name": "name1"},
    {2: 3265, "name": "name2"},
    {3: 6319, "name": "name3"},
    {4: 2539, "name": "name4"},
    {5: 1734, "name": "name5"}

]
```

Also if you want to access using x[0]["name0"] -

```
  x = [ {"name0": 5673},
    {"name1": 3265},
    {"name2": 6319},
    {"name3": 2539},
    {"name4": 1734 }

]
```

Also dictionaries aren't ordered, and don't have indices. Values can only be accessed by keys that exist in the dictionary (else you will get a KeyError). If you want to access x[0], either there specifically has to be a key called 0, or x has to be a list as shown above. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the individual elements of your key in a for and only return the value if it matches some logic you make up. Or you could just convert your data into a proper (list of) dictionary(s) containing data structured in a way you can query it anyway you like.